# Interceptor declared in app.module is not intercepting call from one lazy loaded module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-http-interceptors

I have created an interceptor to add the authentication token and refresh the authentication token if it expires like below:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomInterceptors implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
             // ... implementation details
    }

}
```

I have registered this interceptor in the main module of angular (app.module) like below:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        HttpClientModule, 
        MatSnackBarModule,

        // Fuse modules
        FuseModule.forRoot(fuseConfig),
        FuseProgressBarModule,
        FuseSidebarModule,
        FuseThemeOptionsModule,

        // App modules
        LayoutModule,
        LightboxModule
      
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [AuthGuard, UsersService, ErrorService, {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: CustomInterceptors,
        multi: true
    }]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

I have two lazy loaded modules AModule and BModule like below:

```
-- AModule
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '**',
        component: AComponent,
        resolve: {
            interventions: AService
        }
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
        MatButtonModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatRippleModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        TranslateModule.forChild(),
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
        FuseSharedModule,
        FuseConfirmDialogModule,
        FuseSidebarModule,
        FuseDeleteInfoModule
    ],
    providers: [
        AsService
    ]
})
export class AModule {
}


--------------------------------------------------------------------


--BModule
const routes: Routes = [
     {
        path: '**',
        component: BComponent,
        resolve: {
            contacts: BService
        }
    },
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        BComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
        MatButtonModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatRippleModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatAutocompleteModule,
        FuseSharedModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        FuseConfirmDialogModule,
        FuseSidebarModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        MatChipsModule,
        MatTableExporterModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        TranslateModule.forChild(),
        MatPaginatorModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatCardModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule,    
        GalleryModule,
        LightboxModule,
        
    ],
    providers: [
        BService,  
        // {
        //     provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        //     useClass: CustomInterceptors,
        //     multi: true
        // }
    ]
})
export class BModule {
}
```

The Routing for the two lazy loading modules is like below:

```
   {
        path: 'A',
        loadChildren: './a/a.module#AModule',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard], 
        data: { roles: ['Administrator', 'Supervisor','Operator']}
    },
    {
        path: 'B',
        loadChildren: './b/b.module#BModule',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard], 
        data: { roles: ['Administrator']}
    }
```

The problem is that the interceptor is not working for calls made from the BModule but it works successfully for the AModule.

I have found a workaround to this, to add the interceptor in the providers section of the BModule. This isn't right because I am basically instantiating another object of the interceptor in BModule. I want to have the interceptor declared in the app.module to be shared among all lazy loaded modules.

I will appreciate any help or guide to a solution to this problem.

Regards,
Rando.

P.S

Another lazy load module(Lets called C module) that was working, broke down like the B module when someone committed some changes. I ran a  `git diff` to see the differences that made the module stop working. The result is like below:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
@@ -134,7 +138,10 @@ const routes: Routes = [
         MatCardModule,
         ReactiveFormsModule,
         MatListModule,
-        FormsModule
+        FormsModule,
+        GalleryModule,
+        LightboxModule,
+        ImageGalleryModule
     ],
     providers: [
        CService,
```

I made some tests, I was able to identify that interceptor will stop working for the module that imports ImageGalleryModule. The following is the ImageGalleryModule:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ImageGalleryComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        MatButtonModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatRippleModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatTableExporterModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        MatSortModule,
        TranslateModule.forChild(),
        MatPaginatorModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        FuseSharedModule,
        FuseConfirmDialogModule,
        FuseSidebarModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatChipsModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatAutocompleteModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        GalleryModule,
        LightboxModule,

    ],
    providers: [
        DatePipe,
    ],
    exports:[
        ImageGalleryComponent
    ]
})
export class ImageGalleryModule {
}
```

This is strange that importing this module causes the interceptor to not work since this module does not Import or Export the HttpClientModule.

Comment: do you have a stackblitz or something else to test on? from what I can see you have everything correct for you to intercept all http calls

Comment: [`forRoot` moduleWithProviders](https://angular.io/guide/migration-module-with-providers) method should help you.

Comment: No, I haven't created a stackblitz, I am debugging from the project. In the beginning, I thought that BModule would have imported HttpClientModule and that would have overridden the interceptor but from what I saw in imports it is not present.

Comment: Hi  @PankajParkar , can you please be more specific

Comment: @RandoShtishi you have to create forRoot method inside `SharedModule`/`CoreModule` and while importing this module use `ShareModule.forRoot()` method. And make sure `forRoot` method have `providers: [InterceptorService]`. Check [`forRoot`](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#the-forroot-pattern) docs, pretty much everything mentioned there

Comment: @PankajParkar, this way all lazy load module will need to import the interceptor, even though will be no duplicates of the interceptor instance, still it doesn't look right to me. I want to declare the interceptor from the root module and be imported implicitly without the need of me declaring explicitly in the lazy load modules.

Comment: @RandoShtishi in that case make sure that you've imported `HttpClientModule` in `AppModule` only..

Comment: @RandoShtishi anyways, almost all the times `CoreModule`/`ShareModule` will be imported to feature module, so just you have to call `forRoot` method with that. Not sure what you see wrong here.

Comment: @PankajParkar I want to find the conflict that is causing this behavior. I have searched for HttpClientModule in the project and didn't found any reference except in the app module.

Comment: @RandoShtishi can you please change `@Injectable({ providerIn: 'root' })` of `CustomInterceptors`, that should solve the problem.

Comment: @PankajParkar that cannot solve the problem, unfortunately, the ```HttpClientModule``` is imported by a third-party module.

Comment: OMG, that's the issue

Comment: @PankajParkar do you know a solution that would not require to remove the imports of the third party library and also does not create multiple instances of the interceptors?

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround and not a solution to the problem. So this will not be marked as an accepted answer.

I will start by describing the problem:

`HTTP_INTERCEPTOR` are reset when lazy-loaded module import `HttpClientModule`. All interceptors are set up to work on a single instance of the HttpClient service. The moment that the lazy-loaded module imports `HttpClientModule`, it creates a new instance of HttpClient service. This new instance is injected in all components of the lazy loaded module and every call made from this instance is not intercepted by the interceptor declared in the app-module.

In my case, I searched all around the project and didn't find any import of `HttpClientModule` except the app module. After hours of debugging, I found out that BModule and CModule imported ImageGalleryModule that was the culprit for these behaviours.
After investigating in ImageGalleryModule, I found out that the modules `GalleryModule`, `LightboxModule`  imported the HttpClientModule.

**When lazy-loaded module imports a module that imports the HttpClientModule, the interceptors are no longer available because a new instance of HttpClient is created for that lazy-loaded module.**

WorkAround:

I refactored all my services provided in the app module in a separate module called CoreModule like below:

```
@NgModule({
    imports:[

    ],
    declarations: [
    ],
    providers: [
    ]
})

export class CoreModule {

    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
          ngModule: CoreModule,
          providers: [
            AuthGuard, Service A, Service B, Service C, 
            [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CustomInterceptors, multi: true }]
          ],
        };
      }
}
```

After that imported CoreModule in app-module and in the lazy-loaded modules like below:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
...
    ],
    imports: [
...
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
...
```

I don't consider this as a solution because we have created a separate interceptor for the lazy-loaded module that import `GalleryModule`. We have three instances of the interceptor:

- The interceptor instantiated in app-module and AModule
- The interceptor instantiated in BModule
- The interceptor instantiated in CModule