# Angular v16 Standalone component not working with Interceptor?

Tags: angular, interceptor, angular-httpclient-interceptors

Angular version 16, MoneyComponent is a standalone component.

Application structure is
src\app\pages\money. Only one page `moneyForms` needs interceptor to send in additional info to API HttpPost, so instead of adding the interceptor into `app.module`, it's added to a sub lazy load module, `money.module.ts`:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { moneyFormsComponent } from './money-forms.component';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { AuthInterceptor } from '../../guards/auth.interceptor';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    moneyFormsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,    
    RouterModule.forChild([
        {
            path:'',  
            component:moneyFormsComponent,
            children: [
              { path: 'money-forms', loadComponent: () => import('../m/m.component').then(t => t.MoneyComponent)}, 
              ...
            ]
        }       
    ]),
  ],
  providers:[
    {  
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,  
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,  
      multi: true  
    },  
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]  
})

export class moneyFormsModule {}
```

Expected info is not adding into header, so I simplified the AuthInterceptor as

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpHeaders, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';  
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';  
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';  
  
@Injectable()  
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {  
  constructor() {}  
  
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {  
    console.log("--- Hello ----");
    return next.handle(request);  
  }  
}
```

Still console has no **--- Hello ----** printed.

I've checked these posts, made sure `HttpClientModule` is only loaded once, and is in root `app.module.ts`.
[Angular2 Http Interceptor not working in child module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756792/angular2-http-interceptor-not-working-in-child-module)

[Interceptor not intercepting http requests (Angular 6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860293/interceptor-not-intercepting-http-requests-angular-6)

[Interceptor declared in app.module is not intercepting call from one lazy loaded module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64991922/interceptor-declared-in-app-module-is-not-intercepting-call-from-one-lazy-loaded)

[Angular - Interceptor not loading in a lazy loaded module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49855216/angular-interceptor-not-loading-in-a-lazy-loaded-module)

**Update**
Console prints if

- Move registration of interceptor to root app.module.ts
- Replace @Injectable() with @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})

Comment: Did you try using provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi()) in your app.config ? I just checked my project and it's really the only thing different from what i was doing before when i switched to angular 16 (with bootstrap standalone apis ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out:

1. `HttpClientModule` can be in root app.module if needed i.e. used by root components, etc., and can be in a lazy load
   sub-modules too.
2. Make sure all service, factory etc. used in this sub-module are
   registered here, this is where I missed. Then add

   ```
   { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }
   ```
3. Standalone component, add

   ```
   import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
   import { ... } from 'src/app/services/...';
   import { AuthInterceptor } from './guards/auth.interceptor';
   providers: [..., {  
       provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,  
       useClass: AuthInterceptor,  
       multi: true  
     }],
   ```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
import { provideHttpClient, withInterceptors } from '@angular/common/http';
import { httpErrorHandlerInterceptor } from './core/http-error-handler';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([httpErrorHandlerInterceptor]))
  ]
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).